# Python timestamp range return in intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Im using python3 and i am a beginner,
i have this 2 timestamps :

```
StartDate=20191119110000  #2019 NOV 19 11:00:00
EndDate=20191119120000    #2019 NOV 19 12:00:00
```

A 60 minutes range.

I want my code to return timestamp range with the interval i choose, for example:

This range is 60 minutes and interval of 10 minutes would be : #i copied here only the hour and minute

```
1 1100 1110
2 1110 1120
3 1120 1130
4 1130 1140
5 1140 1150
6 1150 1200
```

And if i choose interval of 5 minutes it returns:

```
1 1100 1105
2 1105 1110
3 1110 1115
```

I am really using **epoce** time not a regular timestamp. 
i need it to support float time like  1573989720000.0 epoch time, so i wouldn't miss any millisecond.
How do i do it ?

**EDIT:**
This code works but removes time leftovers.

```
import numpy
start = 1573989000000.0
end = 1573989720000.0
minute = 60000.0
interval = minute *5

for i in numpy.arange(start, end, interval):
    print(i)
```

if i have a range like here with 21 minuts and my interval is 5 minutes, then ill get only 4 answers , and time left will not show as the interval is too big for leftover time. what can i do ?

Comment: Are those `int` or `str`?

Comment: float = 1573989720000.0 epoch time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range function

```py
start = ...
end = ...
interval = ... (in milliseconds)
for i in range(start, end, interval):
    print(i)
```

This should give you what you asked for

Comment: `start = 1573989000000.0
end = 1573989720000.0
interval = 600.000
for i in range(start, end, interval):
    print(i)
`

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @BatchenRegev they need to be integers. Type cast them to integers

Comment: Remove the .0 after the numbers, you need to use integers

Comment: @BatchenRegev if they are all actually `int`s then you can `int()` them.

Comment: Ok i did it it workes but it leaves the "leftover" , fot exsample if my range is 21 minuts and my interval is 5 minutes , i get only 4 results and the leftover is missing, what can i do ?   
code: `import numpy
start = 1573989000000.0
end = 1573989720000.0
minute = 60000.0
interval = minute *5`

Comment: `for i in numpy.arange(start, end, interval):
    print(i)`

please see question edit